# Create a new column to data frame from existing columns using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, function, automation, jupyter-notebook

I am not sure how to build a data frame here but I am looking for a way to take the data from multiple columns and combine them into 1 column. Not as a sum but as a joined value.

```
Ex. MB|Val|34567|W123 -> MB|Val|34567|W123|MB_Val_34567_W123.
```

What I have tried so far is creating a conditions variable that calls a particular column identical to the value in it

```
conditions = [(Groupings_df['GroupingCriteria1'] == 'MB')]
```

then a values variable that would include what I want in the new column

```
values = ['MB_Val_34567_W123']
```

and lastly grouping it

```
Groupings_df['GroupingColumn'] = np.select(conditions,values)
```

This works for 1 row but it would be inefficient to keep manually changing the number in the values variable (34567) over a df with thousands of rows

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you want to create a new column as a concatenation of each row:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'GC1': ['MB'], 'GC2': ['Val'], 'GC3': [34567], 'GC4': ['W123'],
                   'Dummy': [10], 'Other': ['Hello']})
df['GC'] = df.filter(like='GC').astype(str).apply(lambda x: '_'.join(x), axis=1)
print(df)

# Output
  GC1  GC2    GC3   GC4  Dummy  Other                 GC
0  MB  Val  34567  W123     10  Hello  MB_Val_34567_W123
```

Comment: Your answer does help but my apologies I'm needing to add more to this scenario than I originally included. The MB |Val | 34567 | W123 represent the data. The column headers would be GC1_|_GC2_|_GC3_|_GC4_|. Additionally, these are 4 columns out of 15-20 so I am wanting to extract the values from these specific 4 columns and concatenate them in a new column to that same df. Lastly, it would need to iterate through each rows value because each row will contain varying data

Comment: @Joshua3535Econ. I updated my answer, can you kindly check it please?

Comment: I've attempted different iterations of the code you presented. The closest to my intended result printed out one row of data into the new column. Every row after was populated with NaN

Comment: If you don't share data, it's not possible to guess what you really need. Try to update your post with more data, maybe.